# Spring boot lazy initialisation is causing issue for datasource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jenkins, lazy-loading, lazy-initialization

I am trying to implement lazy-initialization in my spring boot microservice.

My application is using below items.

1. Flyway (I have disabled it from yml)
2. postgresql
3. Kafka

Whenever I deploy this microservice on Jenkins *my sping boot application is failing on startup.*

The reason is that on my Jenkins i have nothing installed (kakfa, postgresql or flyway)

What i am adivised is we should use lazy loading, I.e Our application should start without this dependencies and my /health endpoint should be UP.

I have made `lazy-initialization: true` and `flyway: enable: false`

This is starting my application like a charm!

Now whenever i am trying to call `/health` endpoint, I am getting below error.

> Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory
>   method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'

Looking into the logs, It seems spring is trying to connect to database when we are calling `/health` endpoint.

Is there a way to tell spring that check only app is running or not using `/health` and doesn't check other stuff?

Please let me know if I am missing something to provide if you need it.

Thanks!

Comment: try `management.health.db.enabled=false` ?

Comment: @DirkDeyne Thanks dear, It was quite helpful. Now i am not getting such error of jdbc. But still i need to figure out 1 thing, `com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket`. The strange thing is that i have disabled the mongodb configuration from my yml file. I am trying to look into this, Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ok it's `management.health.mongo.enabled=false` :)